# What's the correct way to represent a linear process in CocoaTouch (UIKit)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uikit, ipad, viewcontroller

I need to represent a linear process (think wizard) in an iPad app.

In principle I could use a UINavigationController and just keep pushing new controllers for each step of the process. But this seems rather inefficient since the process I'm modeling has no notion of navigating backwards so all previous views would pointlessly stay around and use up resources.

At the moment I keep adding and removing a subview to one "master" viewcontroller and basically swapping out the contents. This works but feels rather clunky and I hope there is some nicer way to achieve this.

Additionally there needs to be an animated transition between the views. (I have this working at the moment via beginAnimations / commitAnimations)

UPDATE:
To clarify my question: I'm aware that wizards usually have a back button. That's not what I'm building here.
The process that has to be shown possibly has a lot of steps (up to around 30-40 in some cases probably) so I really don't want to have 39 obsolete view controllers taking up ram.

Comment: Even wizard designs on desktops allow you to navigate backwards through the stack, so your design is especially non-standard. If you think there's a chance your users will want the ability to navigate "back", then you should redesign.

Comment: What I'm building isn't a wizard I used that just for explanatory purposes. 
There definitely is no backwards navigation in this process, it's one of the core design criterias of the app

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the `backBarButtonItem` of each view controller's `navigationItem` to `nil` so that you don't show a back button?

Comment: That might work to hide a NavigationController's bar but as I wrote above the concept of stacking views on top of each other doesn't really fit my needs as I never need to go back to a previous view.

Comment: @UloPe right.  My suggestion is to remove the back button altogether.  That way you *couldn't* go back to a different view.

Comment: I understand that, but I would still have the stack of old view controllers that I won't show again "hanging around" in the background.

Comment: What about modifying the navigation controller's stack after pushing a new vc?  You can manipulate the `viewControllers` property to only have the top-most item.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend uinavigationcontrollerdelegate and check every push event the current stack size. Then you can replace with a new reduced array that contains only the desired view controllers. By the way, if you implement a good memory management and release every resource on viewDidDisappear, i'm quite sure that it's not a matter for the os to manage a huge number of "empty" view controllers.
Hope it helps